# What is "gate_gradients" atribute in tensorflow minimize() function in the optimzer class?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

This is the link to TF optimizer class **https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train/optimizers**

Comment: It seems to have to do with how to parallelize the gradient computation and application. See the comment here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L214

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same page that you have linked, if you scroll down a little bit, it says:

> gate_gradients argument that controls the degree of parallelism during the application of the gradients

Comment: Yeah. I saw that. What is that parallelism they mentioned ? For matmul operation think we get two inputs X and Y they say we can calculate gradients for X first and then apply to X while Y not being calculated yet  . What is it ?

Answer (score 15):

GATE_NONE: Take the simple case of a matmul op on two vectors 'x' and 'y'. let the output be L. Now gradient of L wrt x is y and gradient of L wrt y is xT (x transpose). with GATE_NONE it could so happen that the gradient wrt x is applied to modify x before the gradient for y is even calculated. Now when the gradient wrt y is calculated it would be computed equal to modified x which is an error. Of course it won't happen in such a simple case but you could imagine it could happen in more complex/extreme cases

GATE_OP: For each Op, make sure all gradients are computed before they are used. This prevents race conditions for Ops that generate gradients for multiple inputs where the gradients depend on the inputs. (You could see how this prevents the problem of GATE_NONE, though at the price of some parallelism).

GATE_GRAPH: Make sure all gradients for all variables are computed before any one of them is used. This provides the least parallelism but can be useful if you want to process all gradients before applying any of them.(an example of use case is clipping gradients according to global norm before applying them)